# Unable to retrieve VideoView from dialog

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a custom dialog box (playvideo.xml) which has a videoview in it.

I am using the following code, but getting a null pointer exception at `videoView.setVideoURI(video);`

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this,R.style.FullHeightDialog);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.playvideo);


    VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+ R.raw.howtoplaymancalagp);

    //if uncommented, then gives null pointer exception
    //videoView.setVideoURI(video);

     dialog.show();
    //videoView.start();
```

I can't figure out why the videoView is null.

Comment: Asked bazillion times... VideoView doesn't belong to Activity but to dialog... So findviewbyid will not find it...  Use Google to find the answer before asking

Comment: The implication is that your `R.layout.playvideo` does not contain a `R.id.videoView`.

Comment: @Selvin adding an 'lol' to that doesn't get your point across, it just sounds rude. It's possible what karaokyo suggested could be the issue in some cases, but it's not here. It's a very easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `findViewById()` on the Activity, and the video view is not found there.

On this line, you set the content view of the dialog:

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.playvideo);
```

If you want to get the videoView, you need to call findViewById on that view. Try this:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) dialog.getView().findViewbyId(R.id.videoView);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!     VideoView videoView = (VideoView) dialog.findViewbyId(R.id.videoView);   worked

Comment: If I wanted to add a MediaController, I tried MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(vv);
        vv.setMediaController(mediaController);.....but it didn't work probably because of "this"......it would be great if u could help me out in ths issue too...thankyou!!!

Comment: I wanted to know how to access the MediaController from the dialog. because i think MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);  is the problem.....Thanks for helping!!